# Animating particles from a SKEmitterNode

Tags: ios, animation, sprite-kit, skaction

The goal is to animate particles coming from a `SKEmitterNode,` but the following code doesn't work. The particles don't change texture. They only show the first texture -- or more specifically the original image used in the Xcode Particle Editor -- during the lifetime.

The particle lifetime is longer than the frame duration so this isn't the issue.

```
            // Create animation textures
            let animationAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: atlasFilename)
            var animationFrames = [SKTexture]()

            // Set number of animation frames
            let numImages = animationAtlas.textureNames.count

            // Load texture array
            for i in 0..<numImages {
                let textureName = "\(texturePrefix)\(i)"
                animationFrames.append(animationAtlas.textureNamed(textureName))
            }

            // Create emitter node w/ animation on each particle
            let emitterNode = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: EmitterFilename)!
            let animation = SKAction.animate(with: animationFrames, timePerFrame: 0.05)                
            emitterNode.particleAction = animation

            // Define fade out sequence
            let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: sparkleFadeOutDur)
            let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            let sequence = SKAction.sequence([fadeOut, remove])

            // Add emitter node to scene
            addChild(emitterNode)
            emitterNode.run(sequence)
```

Answer (score 0):

While your code looks flawless and this may potentially be a bug of the particle engine, it's worth assuming that your animation runs out of frames before the particles become large or visible enough so that you see the animation perform. If that's the case, after the animation is finished the texture may revert back to the original texture that you're seeing.

To check if that's the issue, you may want to wrap your animate action into a repeatForever action:

```
repeatAction = SKAction.repeatForever(animation)
```

and then change the particleAction assignment as follows:

```
emitterNode.particleAction = repeatAction
```

It's worth noting that Apple's documentation seems contradictory. At this page (https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417828-animate) we see: "This action can only be executed by an SKSprite​Node object."

Particles are clearly not accessible sprite nodes as this page (https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skemitternode) states, but at the same time they should behave like sprites:

"For the purpose of using actions on particles, you can treat the particle as if it were a sprite. This means you can perform other interesting tricks, such as animating the particle’s textures."